# How can I force the game to check my online status?

Tags: farmville-country-escape

Game keeps saying I am offline, even though I have both wifi and data enabled (so that really should never be a problem). Is there a way to force it to check my status, or to try reconnecting? I wanna sell my stuff! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the game is generally offline, until you tap one of the icons/objects that requires you to be online.  The game will check at that point whether or not you are online.

The Market, the Mailbox, the Co-Op Sign, and the little "three people" icon in the upper right all seem to trigger an online check.

I turned off my wifi and mobile data, and got errors when trying to interact with these objects.  Turning my wifi back on and then tapping one of them cleared the error.